# how to check the value of an input correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, radio-button

i have made a little quiz
but i have one last problem
when clicking next button it checks to see if the value is not undfinded.
if its true it checks to see if the client choosen radio is equals to the spouse correct answer then 
a var correctAnswer get +1.
the problem is that at the first question its working (checking to see that a client really choose something out of the answers and checking to see if its correct)
but when the next question is presented its not working. I tried to figure it out but came with no sulotion...
also check jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/boazmier/ru8Qj/1/
i have tried to put the checkClientChoice function into the loadquestion function it didnt worked as well

```
var allQuestions = {
    question: {
        question0: {
            question: "Who is the first Prime Minister of Israel?",
            choices: ["David", "Rabin", "Peres", "Bibi"],
            correct: "David"
        },
        question1: {
            question: "What Is israel date of birth?",
            choices: ["1948", "1958", "1950", "1944"],
            correct: "1948"
        },
        question2: {
            question: "What is PhoneGap framework for?",
            choices: ["apache", "apps", "server", "client"],
            correct: "apps"
        }
    },

    correctAnswer: 0
};

var allquestion = allQuestions["question"];

var calcAnswers =allQuestions["correctAnswer"];

var qNum = 0;

var value;

//function that deploies the question and the choices to the section.
function loadquestions(qNum){
    $(".question").text(allquestion["question"+qNum]["question"]); //set the the question to the title
    for(var i=0;i<allquestion["question"+qNum]["choices"].length;){
        //loops throughout the li's
        var cH =(allquestion["question"+qNum]["choices"][i]); // a var that holds text of choice in poistion i
        $("label[for=li"+i+"]").text(cH); //define for every label its text
        $("#li"+i).attr("value",cH); //define for every input radio its value which is equals to label which is equals to var cH
        i++;//count i with +1
    }
}

//function that fires when clicked the "next" button and when trigered hides the current question and presents the next one

function checkClientChoice(){
 $("#next").click(function(){
     value = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();

     if(value == undefined){
        alert("Please choose a valid answer");
    }
    else {
        if(allquestion["question0"]["correct"] == value){
            alert("correct");
            calcAnswers++;
            alert(calcAnswers);
            qNum++;
            loadquestions(qNum);
        }
         else{
            qNum++;
            loadquestions(qNum);
        }
    }
});
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    loadquestions(qNum);
    checkClientChoice();
});
```

Comment: sidenote : you should really be using array keys `0,1,2,...` instead of `question0,question1,etc..`

Comment: It's neat and conventional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, here what we got:

```
if(allquestion["question0"]["correct"] == value)
```

You always check answer to the very first question. You should change this to

```
if(allquestion["question" + qNum]["correct"] == value)
```

Or track question num in function `checkClientChoice` some other way.

Comment: Oh i see now :) i guess i needed a fresh eyes to check my code... thnak mate.